# How do I get the values and id's of multiple select lists and pass it to AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, selectlist

I am trying to iterate through a number of selects in a cell of a table (they are not in a form). I have a submit button when pressed is supposed to retrieve the values and id of each select list which I will pass to the server via AJAX and PHP. My table is a table of students of a course. The table contains the students name and their attendance for a lesson in the course.

This is my table on Pastebin and jsFiddle. http://pastebin.com/NvRAbC7m and http://jsfiddle.net/4UheA/

Please note that this table is entirely dynamic. The no. of rows and the info in them is dynamically driven.

This is what I'm trying to do right now with jQuery. Please excuse the logic or the complete nonsense that is my JavaScript skills. I don't actually know what I'm doing. I'm just doing trial and error.

```
$('#saveAttendances').live('click', function()
{
    var attendSelect = $('.attendSelect');
    var students = new Array();
    //get select list values and id. 
    for(var i in attendSelect)
    {
        students['student_id'] += attendSelect[i].id;
        students['student_id']['attedance'] += attendSelect[i].value;
        console.log(students['student_id']);
    }
    //after retrieving values, post them through ajax
    // and update the attendances of students in PHP
    $.post("",{ data: array }, function(msg)
    {
         alert(msg);
    }); 

});
```

How do I get the values and id's of each select list and pass it to AJAX?

Comment: ids should not begin with a number

Comment: How would I find the student's id then? Where would I put it?

Comment: What format do you want the data passed as? An array, JSON, ...?

Comment: I'm not sure. Whatever is easiest I guess on the PHP side.

Comment: @JohnathanAu something like `id-344` then access it with `$('#id-'+id)`

Comment: Argh, I've done it for entire site. This is going to be a pain to change. I didn't think about this

Comment: @JohnathanAu, no better time than now to start doing things the right way! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit

If you insist on going against jQuery's grain and using invalid HTML, here's a suitable solution for you:

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function(){
       var data = $(".attendSelect").wrap('<form/>').serialize();
       $.post('process.php', data, function(response){ ... });
       return false;            
    });
});​
```

**Worth mentioning,** this example does not rely on fanciful `.on()` or `.live()` calls. However, this requires you to have the proper `name` attribute set on your `<select>` elements as described below.  This also resolves your invalid numeric `id` attributes issue.

[See it working here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NNcXn/1/)

---

#### Original Answer

First off, some minor changes to your HTML.  You need to wrap your `<select>` elements in a `<form>` tag.  Using the form tag will give you access to jQuery's [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method which is the exact functionality you're looking for.  Personally, I'd recommend doing things the jQuery Way™ instead of implementing your own form a serialization.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Next, your `td` have non-unique IDs.  Let's update those to use a `class` attribute instead of an `id`.  E.g.,

```
<td class="studentName">Aaron Colman</td>
```

Secondly, your `<select>` elements could benefit from a `name` attribute to make form processing way easier.

```
<select class="attendSelect" name="students[241]">
    ...

<select class="attendSelect" name="students[270]">
    ...

<select class="attendSelect" name="students[317]">
    ...
```

Lastly, jQuery's `.serialize()` is going to be your winning ticket.

```
​$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(){
       $.post('process.php', $(this).serialize(), function(response){ ... });
       return false;            
    });
});​
```

Upon submit, the serialized string will look something like

```
students[241]=Late&students[270]=Absent&students[317]=default
```

See it working here on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sHC5q/)

Comment: Hey, thanks but my select lists are not in a form. They're in a table so I have to iterate through each select list.

Comment: Then put them in a `<form>`. Using `<select>` out of a form is invalid.  Plus, you get tons of added js functionality for simply wrapping them in a form. You can use `.serialize()` which is built in to jQuery for this specific purpose.  Or you can write your own serialization method as demonstrated in these other answers. Personally, I'd go with the jQuery Way™ of doing things.

Comment: @JohnathanAu, I've updated my post to support your no-form implementation.  Please see the edit.

Comment: Hey, how would I wrap them in a form because the select lists are in separate cells and my submit button is outside of the table?

Comment: @JohnathanAu wrap the whole table in a `<form>` element? My Original answer has a jsfiddle with a working form example. Otherwise see my edited answer and corresponding fiddle for the no-form example. (I'm still recommending my original answer as it's much better HTML; it resolves your non-unique IDs, gives name attributes to your selects, resolves your numeric id issue, and adds a valid form wrapper for your selects.)

Comment: Yeah, if it's better then I'll have to do this. Will it not be data intensive in that it'll be sending unnecessary data i.e. the entire table to the server?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9696/discussion-between-macek-and-johnathan-au)

Answer (score 1):

`live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, use `on()` instead

http://api.jquery.com/on/

students is an array, so I don't think you can do `students['student_id']`, if you would like to push an array of student, you can:

```
$('#saveAttendances').on('click', function() {
    var students = [];

    // iterate through <select>'s and grab key => values
    $('.attendSelect').function() {
        students.push({'id':$(this).attr('id'), 'val':$(this).val()});
    });

    $.post('/url.php', {data: students}, function() { // do stuff });
});
```

in your php:

```
var_dump($_POST); // see what's inside :)
```

As @nathan mentioned in comment, avoid using number as the first character of an ID, you can use `'student_<?php echo $id ?>'` instead and in your `.each()` loop:

```
students.push({'id':$(this).attr('id').replace('student_', ''), 'val':$(this).val()});
```

Comment: I noticed that in console.log for my snippet, it has A LOT of undefined, 181 of them. Is that normal? It would log the id's then have a lot of undefined.

Comment: @JohnathanAu yes, as I said, since students is an Array, doing `students[student_id]` would have no effect on students, then on your `students['student_id']['attedance'] += attendSelect[i].value;`, it will throw undefined

Comment: @NiftyDude, I think you want `.attr()` instead of `.prop()` as `id` is an *attribute*

Comment: @JohnathanAu sorry bout that :(

Comment: lol. I noticed the .replace(). What does that do in that chain? It's selected the select list's id then ... ?

Comment: ok, since it is not recommendable to use number as id, you need to use `<select id="student_5" class="attendSelect">`, for example. So in my loop, since you are only interested in the 5 portion, I did a replace of `student_` to nothing, which gives you 5 (which is the id). That's basically what it does.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Updated to iterate over `select` instead of `tr`.

Perhaps you want something like below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/4UheA/6/)

```
var $attendSelect  = $('#tutorTable tbody tr select');
var students = {};

$attendSelect.each (function () { //each row corresponds to a student               
    students[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
});
```

This would give you an object like below,

```
students = { '241': 'Late', '270': 'Absent', '317': 'default' };
```

If the above is not the desired structure then modify the `.each` function in the code.

**For ex:** For a structure like below,

```
students = [{ '241': 'Late'}, {'270': 'Absent'}, {'317': 'default'}];
```

You need to change the code a little,

```
 var students = [];
 ...
 ...
 students.push({$dd.attr('id'): $dd.val()});
```

Comment: I think you want `.attr()` instead of `.prop()` as id is an *attribute*.

Answer (score 1):

Here's jQuery that will build an object you can pass to your script:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var attendance = new Object;
    $('select').each(function() {
        attendance[$(this).attr('id')] = $(':selected', this).text();
    })
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4UheA/5/)**.

This results in: `{241:"Late",270:"Absent",317:"Late"}`

Answer (score 1):

```
var $select = $('.attendSelect'),
    students = [];
$('body').on('click', '#saveAttendances', function() {
    $select.each(function(k, v) {
        students[k] = {
            student_id : $(this).attr('id'),
            attedance  : $(this).val()
        };
    });
    console.log(students);
});
```

Comment: I think you want `.attr()` instead of `.prop()` as id is an *attribute*. You're the third person to make this mistake in this thread.  What is going on in here?